# An analytic function having no element of negative x-axis in its range

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function defined on open unit disc such that range of f is contained in $\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

Then I need to tell whether $f$ must be a constant function.

I was thinking of discarding this by an example. But I am not able to find one.

Please help.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! In that other question, $f$ is an entire function - here $f$ is just defined in a disk (making the answer totally different as well as much more trivial).

Comment: Is the function $z\mapsto z+2$ constant?

Comment: Isn't $f(-3+0i) = -1+0i$ in this which contradicts the hypothesis?

Comment: You said $f$ was defined in the unit disk. The point $-3$ is not in the domain of$f$.

Comment: Oh yes..overlooked that fact. Thanks